# How to get converted csv into json with fields and data format in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, papaparse

I am trying to convert CSV to JSON using Papa Parse 5. Below Data that I have

```
Firstname,Lasname,City
Foo,bar, Mumbai
abc,def,Pune
xyz,pqr, Bangalore
```

Code

```
Papa.parse(file, {
      complete: (result) => {
       console.log('result.data:', result.data);
      }
})
```

Here "file" is the one file I am importing from local. the data is in the above format,
and  I want to get it converted into the bellow JSON format.

```
{
    "fields": ["Firstname", "Lasname", "],
    "data": [
        ["foo", "bar", "Mumbai"],
        ["abc", "def", "Pune"],
        ["xyz","pqr", "Bangalore"]
    ]
}
```

reference code sandbox- https://codesandbox.io/s/9nchp
reference - https://www.papaparse.com/docs
Please help me to convert

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are two solutions (at least).
You can set "headers: false" and the data will come back as just the cell values. However, the first row *will* be the header, so call `results.data.shift()` to delete it. Then you should be all set.

The other approach is to convert the data to the format you want. When "header: true", the header row becomes the 'key' for each object, so you have an array of objects like this:

```
[{
  "Firstname" : "foo",
  "Lastname" : "bar",
  "City" : "Mumbai"
}, ... ]
```

To get an array (every row in your csv) with just the values, do this:

```
result.data.map(o=>Object.values(o))
```

Resulting in:

```
[
  ["foo", "bar", "Mumbai"],
  ...
]
```

(Also call `event.preventDefault()` in your form handler to prevent a submit behavior.)

Good luck!

Comment: Fair warning, this technique may "work by accident". Beware of how keys in objects are ordered and preserved or not preserved. This can be implementation dependent, so a good place for a unit test to catch unexpected/changed results when running in different environments.